# How do we start a docker container after a specific container is up

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I have a setup with 3 docker containers, containerX use RabbitMQ for communication.

1. RabbitMQ container
2. Container1
3. Container2

***Issue -*** When *`docker compose up`* is run, RabbitMq takes ~2s to be ready, by then the other containers start and exit as rabbimq is not up yet.

With `restart: on-failure` in compose file, the other containers are up once rabbitmq container is ready

***Is there a way to avoid this and request other containers to wait until rabbitMQ(or a specific container) is up***

or a possibility where once a docker container is up it triggers another docker container to start

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: the real problem is those under containers depend on RMQ to actually work, which is something that you'll anyhow need to tackle...